# Visual Studio 2012 SSDT - SQL Schema Compare Hanging

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, schema, sql-server-data-tools

I hope I don't embarrass myself with this question, but here goes...

Trying to use VS2012 SSDT to do a Schema Compare.

1. I have entered a source and target database connection using the sa
   and checked save password.
2. I have click test connection and both
   are easily connecting.
3. Next, I click compare.

This is were it all goes into limbo.  Center screen says "Loading..."  Status bar says "Initializing Comparison..."  It just stays here...  I have let it run for 24 hrs and no change.

I have tried a SQL2008 to a SQL2008 compare, a SQL2012 to a SQL2012 as well as a mix.  No difference.  It stays hung up in limbo.

I did have the very first time I tried it work. Unfortunately, that was just a quick test to make sure all was working and now I cannot reproduce a working compare.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!!

02/06/2016: A trace has lead to an issue, but I do not know the cause.  It seems that it looses information about the target and source.  Here is the last good event.  From this point forward it just loops.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Microsoft-SQLServerDataToolsVS" Guid="{77142e1c-50fe-42cc-8a75-00c27af955c0}" />
        <EventID>75</EventID>
        <Version>1</Version>
        <Level>5</Level>
        <Task>11</Task>
        <Opcode>0</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x800</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-02-06T08:18:15.920483700Z" />
        <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
        <Execution ProcessID="5936" ThreadID="5740" ProcessorID="4" KernelTime="75" UserTime="1350" />
        <Channel />
        <Computer />
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="traceId">      17</Data>
        <Data Name="message">SchemaCompareParticipantForDatabase: Name=[WarrenCity_OH_RMS], ConnectionString=[Data Source=IDN-DEVSERVER;Initial Catalog=WarrenCity_OH_RMS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=idnsa;Password=idnservice;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Application Name=&quot;Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, Schema Compare&quot;]: baselineStamp=Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.DesignServices.DriftDetection.DatabaseStamp</Data>
    </EventData>
    <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
        <Level>Verbose </Level>
        <Keywords>
            <Keyword>Logging </Keyword>
        </Keywords>
        <Task>Logging </Task>
        <Message>SchemaCompare : SchemaCompareParticipantForDatabase: Name=[WarrenCity_OH_RMS], ConnectionString=[Data Source=IDN-DEVSERVER;Initial Catalog=WarrenCity_OH_RMS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=idnsa;Password=idnservice;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Application Name=&quot;Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, Schema Compare&quot;]: baselineStamp=Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.DesignServices.DriftDetection.DatabaseStamp </Message>
    </RenderingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Microsoft-SQLServerDataToolsVS" Guid="{77142e1c-50fe-42cc-8a75-00c27af955c0}" />
        <EventID>75</EventID>
        <Version>1</Version>
        <Level>5</Level>
        <Task>11</Task>
        <Opcode>0</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x800</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-02-06T08:20:41.790142400Z" />
        <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
        <Execution ProcessID="5936" ThreadID="5740" ProcessorID="0" KernelTime="7020" UserTime="77355" />
        <Channel />
        <Computer />
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="traceId">      17</Data>
        <Data Name="message">DeploymentTargetComparer: context=[SchemaCompareContext: DataModel=[Source=[Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.SchemaCompare.SchemaCompareParticipantForDatabase], Target=[Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.SchemaCompare.SchemaCompareParticipantForDatabase]], UserDatabaseScript=[], MasterDatabaseScript=[], ResultFlags=[0]]: ctor</Data>
    </EventData>
    <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
        <Level>Verbose </Level>
        <Keywords>
            <Keyword>Logging </Keyword>
        </Keywords>
        <Task>Logging </Task>
        <Message>SchemaCompare : DeploymentTargetComparer: context=[SchemaCompareContext: DataModel=[Source=[Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.SchemaCompare.SchemaCompareParticipantForDatabase], Target=[Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.SchemaCompare.SchemaCompareParticipantForDatabase]], UserDatabaseScript=[], MasterDatabaseScript=[], ResultFlags=[0]]: ctor </Message>
    </RenderingInfo>
</Event
```

Comment: "Any suggestions would be appreciated!!" - ok as you seem willing! When it is in the hung state check sql for blocked connections (select * from sys.sysprocesses where blocked <> 0) (please don't tell anyone I still use sys.sysprocesses) - it could be that something on sql is blocking it, it happened with a system I worked on once!

Comment: @EdElliott- Checked for Blocks.  None Found.

Comment: again it might not lead anywhere but you could enable SSDT and DacFx ETL logging and see if you can see anything about why it is failing, the logs are internal trace logs so might not be of much use, this will show you how to enable the logging: https://the.agilesql.club/Blogs/Ed-Elliott/Enable-SSDT-And-DacFx-Logging

Comment: @EdElliott - Trace seems to show it is loosing the details of the Source and Target.  I have adjusted my Question with more details.  I appreciate your time!

Comment: I was hoping you would see an actual error - do you get this on more than one machine? Also what version of SSDT are you using?

Comment: @EdElliott- SSDT v11.1.41025.0
Yes every machine in building has same issue...

Comment: Are you comparing 2 live databases? or sql project to database?  Can you do it on the command line using sqlpackage.exe (project/dacpac --> live database)

Comment: @EdElliott - Both DBs are live.  Using SQLPackage.exe the results are the same.  It builds the dacpac for both the source and target ok, but locks up when running /a:Script.

Comment: Hmmm, if you ping me at ed999@agilesql.club999 (remove all 6 9's) I'll be happy to look at a memory dump, that might tell us more.

Comment: @EdElliott-thanks for the offer but I am afraid that the admins here will frown on that.

Comment: I would suggest ruling out the live database vs SSDT - if you can, export your Target DB as a .dacpac and run your SQLPackage.exe /a.Script against that. Rinse and repeat with the Source DB. If it runs successfully with one of the live databases removed, then the problem will be connection management etc at the live server/database end.